# run script multiple times on .txt files and save each output in single table in r

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I have to run a correlation analysis on over 100 .txt files. I have a script which reads a single file, organizes the data in the appropriate way that I need, and then stores the correlation value as a new variable. The script is quite large as the data gets reformatted a lot.

my question. How can I make this script run repeatedly on all the 100+ .txt files, and stores the single correlation value for all 100+ in a single DF? Ideally the final DF would consist of two columns, one with the .txt ID and another with the Correlation coefficient, and it would have 100+ rows.

Can I literally copy and paste the script into a for loop? If so how would that appear? I'm a newbee!
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use `lapply` to run on multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) mentioned, you can do this with `lapply`.  Without seeing your data, I would recommend something like this:

```
my.files <- list.files(pattern = "txt")  # use a pattern that only matches the files you want to read in
output <- lapply(my.files, correlation_function)

# Combine list of outputs into a single data.frame
output.df <- do.call(rbind, output)
```

This assumes that you have a function called `correlation_function` that takes a filename as input, `load`s the file into `R`, runs the correlation analysis, and returns a `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!